# His breath smells strongly of tobacco. ('of' usage)

Tags: prepositions

> His breath smells strongly of tobacco.

I know 'smell' is used as follows:

1. smell + like
2. smell + of
3. smell + adjective
4. smell + sth + *ing(present participle)*

What's the meaning and/or usage of 'of' in the example sentence?

Answer (score 0):

If his breath smells of tobacco, it has a smell which comes from the tobacco.

Usually if something smells of (say) apples, then it will smell like apples. But tobacco is a bit different, since the smell comes from the smoke, not the dried leaves.